# Can not find link to download OpenSolaris source code

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

I want to understand how OpenSolaris [ptools](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/solaris_performanceandtools_ch3_processes.pdf)(process tools) works. How exactly  pstack, pmap, pargs etc works, but I can't find any link to its full source code. I can only find an online version of the [source](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/cmd/ptools/). Any advice where I can download source code for offline use?

Comment: I heard that OpenSolaris is not "open" anymore? a quick google for "oracle opensolaris" shows a lot of results like this http://blogs.computerworld.com/16741/oracle_dumps_opensolaris

Comment: Possibly deleted answer now from @JDoe: [Opensolaris with source is available here](https://www.linux-distros.com/opensolaris/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Kristof Provost mentioned, the official source for the code is:

```
ssh://anon@hg.opensolaris.org/hg/project/project-repo
```

Like you said, the source tarballs are now deprecated.

> and I can't install Mercurial :(

? But you should have access to some machine where you can? If not, another possibility would be a live CD with mercurial installed, for example the excellent [GRML](http://grml.org/).

Beside that, I cloned the repository for you ;-) You can find it under: http://solaris.oark.org/usr/src/. What you are looking for is the directory http://solaris.oark.org/usr/src/cmd/ptools/. `wget` should now do the job :-)

Note: I will delete this cloned repository the next weeks...

Have fun.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share tar for that folder? I don't want to over load you server with lots of download request ;)

Comment: Its not problem ;-) the webserver scales fine ;-)

Comment: ok. Starting now :).

Comment: @echox: I am done with the download if you want you can remove the repository. Thanks alot for your efforts to copy and share repository on you server. :)

Comment: thx for the response, no problem. Since we all are using linux/unix such 'tasks' are no big thing ;-)

Comment: hg.opensolaris.org no longer exists. Looks like we now have to either look forks (Illumos) or mirrors ( such as https://github.com/kofemann/opensolaris ).

Answer (score 6):

You can download illumOS code from github. [Here is the link.](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate). You can also download as **[a zip file](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/archive/master.zip).**

Comment: Packages are also available directly, for instance [this](http://pkg.openindiana.org/dev/manifest/0/system%2Fextended-system-utilities%400.5.11%2C5.11-0.151.1.9%3A20140117T210104Z).

Answer (score 6):

Oracle quickly closed down the OpenSolaris project after taking over Sun.

Because of the previously used open source license, the code is still available.

As of 2023, there is only one Mercurial clone of the old Mercurial repository online:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/b23a4dab3d500aa3e57159dfbf2b3f9a5bbf4bd6/log/

NB: that repository isn't just a mirror, but a fork, i.e. after the end of the official SUN.com OpenSolaris history the 'SchilliX' development history follows.

However, one can still hg clone that repository like this:

```
hg clone http://hg.code.sf.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on schillix-on-schillix-on
```

To view and navigate to the end of the OpenSolaris history:

```
hg log -r b23a4da  -f
hg checkout b23a4da
```

Alternatively, one can checkout the nearest tag, i.e. `schillix-on_00` and go back a few commits.

The last genuine OpenSolaris commit is:

```
Sukumar Swaminathan
b23a4da
2010-08-18
6973228 Cannot download firmware 2.103.x.x on Emulex FCoE HBAs
...
```

There is also an archive of the [LSARC/PSARC documents](https://illumos.org/opensolaris/ARChive/) previously published on opensolaris.org.

In general, one can also consult the current [illumos source code browser (-> illumos-gate)](http://src.illumos.org/source/) as [illumos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illumos) is based on the last available OpenSolaris. See also the [Github mirror](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/).

A direct link to the illumos github history, i.e. where OpenSolaris development stopped and the first illumos commit was added:

- https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/commits/master?since=2010-08-18&until=2010-08-18

In the meantime, Illumos development continued, thus some code might include bug fixes and other improvements. But in general, the code should still be very close to the last OpenSolaris state of the art because illumos development resources are quite limited.

When OpenSolaris was still alive, Sun regularly also published [open sourced man page archives](https://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/Manual+Pages). The illumos equivalent is a [browsable man page site](http://illumos.org/man/all) and there are browseable HTML repositories of the last 2009.06 OpenSolaris man pages dump:

- https://www.unix.com/man-page-opensolaris-repository.php
- https://manpath.be/osol

Comment: github.com/nxmirrors is gone for some reason, but I found https://github.com/kofemann/opensolaris .

Comment: @mtraceur Hm, many of these old links are gone. I'm wondering whether this is just normal bit-rot or the result of some lawyers bullying people. However, the kofemann mirror is incomplete, i.e. its last commit is from Feb 4, 2010 whereas the other mirrors went up to Aug 18, 2010. You still see those commits in the illumos repository: https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/commits/master?since=2010-08-18&until=2010-08-18 - i.e. the last commit from Sun is the one I've quoted in my answer, the newer ones contain non-Sun.com review/signed/approve tags.

Comment: @mtraceur found a good Mercurial mirror, updated some links and added some notes.

Answer (score 2):

[Get The Source](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Main/get)

It's possible you'll need to use Mercurial to get it.

Comment: I just saw following comment. "Source tarballs have been deprecated in favour of the onnv project's Mercurial repository."  and I cant install Mercurial :(.

Answer (score 2):

OpenSolaris + source code available [here](https://www.linux-distros.com/opensolaris/)

Answer (score 1):

Download it from the [main download page](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Main/downloads).

Edit (2013, 3 years later): this links to Solaris 11 download. OpenSolaris is no more; you should go to one of the forks, like [IllumOS](http://illumos.org), if you want source material.

Comment: I checked that page but it seems to have only link to live cd and some other Consolidations. Cant find link to source archive. Can you please post the link to source.